How to derive instant-dependent regret for KL-UCB bandit?
I was reading KL-UCB algorithm for bandit with Bernoulli reward from Bandit Algorithms book by Lattimore (Section 10.2), and the regret provided by the algorithm is instant-dependent and it depends on the optimality gap of all arms. I am wondering how we can determine the instant-independent bound for this algorithm where it only depends on the number of arms and the time horizon. Also, given the definition of UCB, what is the confidence level?
Also, is this algorithm the best one among all algorithms for bandit with Bernoulli reward either theoretically or empirically?
